# How to replace all space with "_" for the first quoted string?

Tags: gvim

I have several lines, and each line has 2 quoted string, and I want to replace all space with "_" for the first quoted string.

How to do that? Could I use macro?

```
select 'a b c','a b c' union all
select 'a e1 c d','a e1 c d' union all
select 'a f11 c','a f11 c' union all
select 'a g1 c','a g1 c' union
```

result:

```
select 'a_b_c','a b c' union all
select 'a_e1_c_d','a e1 c d' union all
select 'a_f11_c','a f11 c' union all
select 'a_g1_c','a g1 c' union
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the macro is a good use here :

```
0vi':s/\%V /_/g^M
```

Decomposing the macro :

```
0        " go to the start of the line
vi'      " visually select inside '
:s/       " start a substitute command
\%V      " tell the substitute to operate over the last visual selection
 /_/g    " there is a ' ' here : replace every ' ' with a '_'
^M       " press <CR>
```

Reference for `\%V` : http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace_in_a_visual_selection

You can then go line over line, or execute the macro over all lines at the same time (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3338480/2558252)

Comment: Do you really need to leave visual mode first? I know there are cases when you do, but I think with `\%V` you'd be fine starting the substitute from visual mode. Save some keystrokes :)

Comment: `0f'v;` could be `0vi'`

Comment: I think there is an `<Esc>` missing after the `vi'`, otherwise you have to manually delete the `:'<,'>s/` and retype it. At least in vim 8.0.

Answer (score 6):

A macro like @Nobe4's may be the easiest, but you could also do a substitution. It can be tricky to express the substitution since you want it to be 'global' within the quoted string, but not really global for the line (i.e., replace *all* whitespace, but only for the first quoted string on the line). One way is to do a non-global substitution to replace the whole first quoted string, and for replacement use an expression which makes a global substitution on that string from ' ' to '_'.

```
:%s/'[^']*'/\=substitute(submatch(0), ' ', '_', 'g')/
```

or

```
:%s/'.\{-}'/\=substitute(submatch(0), ' ', '_', 'g')/
```

Maybe this feels a little clunky compared to a macro, but it can be a useful technique sometimes.

**Details**

- `:` - enter cmdline mode
- `%` - for all lines in buffer
- `s` - substitute (the three `/` characters delimit the substitute command, see `:help :substitute`)
- `'.\{-}'` or `'[^']*'` - regex that matches anything surrounded by single quotes
- `\=` - substitute with an expression (see `:help sub-replace-expression`)
- `substitute()` - the expression is a call to `:help substitute()`
- `submatch(0)` - the entire matched string is retrieved with `submatch(0)` and is the first argument to `substitute()`
- `' ', '_'` - the substitution on the string
- `'g'` - global flag, i.e., substitute all occurrences

If we had ended the `:substitute` command with a global flag (`/g`) then it would have substituted all occurrences of quoted strings on the line. As it is, it only does the first. In the call to `substitute()` however we do use the global flag (`'g'`) in order to replace all occurrences of `' '` in the quoted string.

Comment: I like your solution, can you give some more details for the differents parts ?

Comment: It's always good to see examples of advanced search replace usage like this to try to boost one's knowledge.