# Deleting a Latex command multiple times

Tags: filetype-tex, repeated-commands

Indexing a Latex document, I added a lot of `\index[]{}` commands in \footcite prenotes. It's stupid! Anyway, in my code I have a lot of :

```
\footcite[blabla blabla\index[n]{something} blabla.][postnote]{Reference}
```

or sometimes :

```
\footcite[blabla blabla\index[n]{something} blabla\index[n]{otherthing} blabla.][postnote]{Reference}
```

I would like to find some trick to suppress all the `\index[n]{something}` or `\index[n]{otherthing}` stuffs only if they are between the square brackets of a footcite prenote. Is there an easy trick to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `\footcite` is always one line, you could do something like this:

- `%g/\footcite[/s/\index.\{-}[}]//cg` Select every line with "footcite" on it, and *only* on those lines take every string of the form "\index any characters ]" and remove it.

The `c` ensures that if some of the `index`s are outside of the cite and you want to keep those, you can just skip replacing those.

Comment: Arrg! Most of time it is a multiple line prenote. But maybe your tip could help a bit.

Comment: It solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

#### Substitute and nested substitute

Another way, which handles the command being split over multiple lines, is

```
%s/\\footcite\[\_.\{-}\zs\\index\[\_.\{-}]{\(\_.\{-}\)}/\1/gc
```

You would have to run this more than once if you want to remove more than one `\index` command within the same `\footcite[]`. I'm actually not sure in this case how match one thing (`\footcite[]`) but make many substitutions. Normally you can use use a replacement expression and call a 'nested substitute' (`s/pattern/\=substitute()`/, see `:help sub-replace-expression`), but I couldn't figure out how to match the whole `\footcite[]` string properly. So, that is left as a lesson for the reader (and the writer, for another day), or for knowledgeable vimmers to answer in the comments.

#### Global/normal/visual/substitute

Instead you can do it with a global/normal/visual/substitute command:

```
g/\\footcite/normal /[^Mvi]:s/\\index\[[^\]]*\]{\([^}]*\)}/\1/g^M
```

> *nb* the `^M` is `Ctrl-V`+`<CR>`

This command

1. finds the right lines with `global`
2. issues a normal command to
3. searches forward to `[`
4. visually selects inside `[]`
5. substitutes over visual selection

This looks more complicated than it is because (as I learned [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4150/how-can-i-use-the-global-command-to-prepend-document-headers-to-document-li/4156#4156)) you can execute a recorded macro from a global command. So: move cursor to a `\footcite` command and record while you make a manual substitution

`qqf[vi]:s/\\index\[[^\]]*\]{\([^}]*\)}/\1/g`

- `qq` record macro to q register
- `f[` forward to `[` -- or use `/[<CR>` if `[` can be on the next line
- `vi]` visually select inside `[]`
- `:s/...` do the substitution

With the macro recorded you can do

```
:g/\\footcite/normal! @q
```

Comment: You could *probably* fit a `\=substitute()` inside the replacement part, similar to http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3927/1800 (minus the looping part; to remove all the `\index` commands at once).

Comment: @VanLaser Yes! Or like http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4432/how-to-replace-all-space-with-for-the-first-quoted-string/4434#4434, but like I said, this writer needs to see a sunset and a sunrise first :)

Comment: `:s/^You/One` ^  - Roger that & Good night! :)

Comment: @VanLaser It was, thank you :) I was not able to use `\=substitute()` because I couldn't figure out how to match and pass the entire `\footcite[]` to `substitute()` when it contains nested `[]`, that is, how to match to _the correct_ `]`. This seems like it would be a common problem, but I couldn't figure it out. Syntax files solve it for `{}` by making many overlapping matches, but do you know how to do it in a single match?

Comment: `:normal f[v%` could probably help to select a good range, if cursor is on a `footcite`. Then something like `:'<,'>s/\%Vindex ...` to select the exact range (lines & columns) for substitution.